# Else If Does Not Run Correctly on PHP

Tags: php

I have very simple PHP script, but it make me confuses. This is my script

```
<?php

 for($j=0; $j < $muter; $j++)
 {
    if(($_SESSION[KODE]) == ($acak[$j]))
    {
       $sql_update = "UPDATE unik SET kota = '$kota',
                        hadiah = '$hadiah',
                        nama   = '$nama',
                    email  = '$email',
                    status = 'menang'
                       WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION[KODE]'";

      $data_update = mysql_query($sql_update);

      echo "<script>window.location='menang.php';</script>";

      }//end if
      else
      {
         $sql_update = "UPDATE unik SET kota = '$kota',
                      nama   = '$nama',
                      email  = '$email',
                      status = 'kalah'
                   WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION[KODE]'";
       $data_update = mysql_query($sql_update);     

        echo "<script>window.location='kalah.php';</script>";

       }//end of else if
    }//end for

?>
```

The Problem is: The Code Running Well if I Comment This Script

```
echo "<script>
      window.location='kalah.php';
      </script>";
```

But if Dont Comment The JS window.location the script always go to else section(never go to first condition). whereas I need the JS window.location Script.

How can I Fix This?

Im very appreciated your answer.

Thanks

Comment: Clean your script please!

Comment: Indenting & clean code will solve your half problem. Try it out.

Comment: Why use javascript? Use `header("Location: kalah.php")` and `header("Location: menang.php")` It won't solve your problem, but it will simplify it.

Comment: @mseifert I have try to use header. And not work to. Same with I use window.location

Comment: See my answer just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing redirection with loop. Its totally wrong. Because some time `if` executed and some times `else` executed. So browser got confused.

So you have to redirect to any specific page at the end of your loop.

Try to run this code, it will display how many time you will be in if/else condition Based on that you can add logic for redirection after completion of loop.

```
<?php
for($j=0; $j < $muter; $j++)
{
    if($_SESSION['KODE'] == $acak[$j])
    {
        $sql_update = "UPDATE unik SET kota = '$kota',
            hadiah = '$hadiah',
            nama   = '$nama',
            email  = '$email',
            status = 'menang'
            WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION[KODE]'";

        $data_update = mysql_query($sql_update);
        echo "Inside if <br>";
    }//end if
    else
    {
        $sql_update = "UPDATE unik SET kota = '$kota',
            nama   = '$nama',
            email  = '$email',
            status = 'kalah'
            WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION[KODE]'";
        $data_update = mysql_query($sql_update);    
        echo "Inside else <br>";
    }//end of else if
}//end for
?>
```

Comment: So what Should I do to my redirection?

Comment: @Uchsun Redirection should be only once, you can redirect once loop is finished. Because multiple redirection confuse the browser.

Comment: Can I use goto to that script. So after condition, I using goto statement to condition that manage redirection?

Comment: @Uchsun You can use `break;` statement to break the loop and next too loop you make redirection.

Comment: hei, Thanks for the break, I Did it. N it work well and can redirect with no Problems.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is here `WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION[KODE]'";` you need access to $_SESSION values as `WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION['KODE']'";`

```
<?php
for($j=0; $j < $muter; $j++)
{

    if(($_SESSION['KODE']) == ($acak[$j]))
    {

        $sql_update = "UPDATE unik SET kota = '$kota', hadiah = '$hadiah',
        nama   = '$nama',
        email  = '$email',
        status = 'menang'
        WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION['KODE']'";

        $data_update = mysql_query($sql_update);
        echo "<script>
        window.location='menang.php';
        </script>";

    }//end if
    else
    {

        $sql_update = "UPDATE unik SET kota = '$kota',
        nama   = '$nama',
        email  = '$email',
        status = 'kalah'
        WHERE unik_id = '$_SESSION['KODE']'";

        $data_update = mysql_query($sql_update);   


        echo "<script>
        window.location='kalah.php';
        </script>";


    }//end of else if
}//end for

?>
```

Comment: This assumes `KODE` isn't a `define()`d constant, but I think you're right. Assuming he means `$_SESSION['KODE']`, he also needs to fix his `if()` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange attempt. Basically you're looping through something and checking a condition inside your loop. But in any case you echo a window.location change javascript. So this is getting outputted every iteration. This doesn't seem right.

At the end you should be getting zero or more javascript location changes which would be an extremely strange solution to say at least.

Comment: ok, let's say my script is very strange. can u tell me to fix that? Looping and checking condition inside loop and make redirection after it. Maybe your solution is make me clear. I newbie in PHP. Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with what you want to achieve. But since it's always a "redirect" you might as well skip the for loop and simply run  the first iteration (if $muter > 0 do it like when $j is 0 for example)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are numerous things wrong with your code:

1. `$_SESSION[KODE]`. Have you defined a constant named `KODE`? If not then you probably need to put it in quotes, i.e. `$_SESSION['KODE']`.
2. Related to the previous, when interpolating an array item you need to wrap it in curly braces:

   ```
   $sql = "... WHERE `unik_id` = '{$_SESSION['KODE']}'";
   ```
3. Then it is the Javascript... you should use a redirect:

   ```
   header('Location: /menang.php');
   die;
   ```
4. Why are you creating the `$data_update` variable if you are not going to use it?
5. The `mysql_*` extension is deprecated (it has been replaced by newer and better extensions).
6. You have a lot of variables that are not defined anywhere. Is this file included by some other file?

Comment: Thanks for your Attention. For $_SESSION I HAVE Defined. actually I have been explain on my question. it running well if I Comment my redirection on else section. Its true I dont Write All my script on that Qustion because I Think maybe it To long. Do you need to see complete one page ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 reasons you might not be redirecting properly

1) immediately after your `header("Location: ")` statements, you should put `die();` otherwise the php will continue to execute. For example:

```
header("Location: kalah.php");
die();
```

2) You must NOT have outputted anything to the screen (for example, `echo` statements) otherwise, it will not redirect. You can look into [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

3) Lastly, you may not be reaching the correct place in the code. Ignacio Ocampo has some good advice above. Put some debug code with `die('here')` statements in it to make sure you end up where you think you should be.

Lastly, make sure you have at the top of you php

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
}
```